# Testing log.Fatalf in go?

Tags: testing, go

I'd like to achieve 100% test coverage in go code. I am not able to cover the following example - can anyone help me with that?

```
package example

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func checkIfReadable(filename string) (string, error) {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot read the file... how to add coverage test for this line ?!?")
    }
    return "", nil
}

func main() {
    checkIfReadable("dummy.txt")
}
```

Some dumy test for that:

```
package example

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestCheckIfReadable(t *testing.T) {
    someResult, err := checkIfReadable("dummy.txt")
    if len(someResult) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("this will not print")
        t.Fail()
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("this will not print")
        t.Fail()
    }
}

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
...
}
```

The issue is that `log.Fatalf` calls `os.Exit` and go engine dies.

- I could modify the code and replace built-in library with my own - what makes the tests less reliable.
- I could modify the code and create a proxy and a wrapper and a .... in other words very complex mechanism to change all calls to `log.Fatalf`
- I could stop using built-in log package... what is equal to asking "how much is go built-in worth?"
- I could live with not having 100% coverage
- I could replace `log.Fataf` with something else - but then what is the point for built-in `log.Fatalf`?
- I can try to mangle with system memory and depending on my OS replace memory address for the function (...) so do something obscure and dirty
- Any other ideas?

Comment: There is no answer to this question (it's highly opinion-based). Personally I see zero value in 100% line coverage (100% test coverage is impossible because it would require every line be tested *in every possible program state and with every possible set of inputs*). I'd also say there are very few places that should call log.Fatalf; most functions, *especially* utility functions like `checkIfReadable`, should return an error, not crash the program.

Comment: I recommend reading https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/05/lets-talk-about-logging

Comment: If you are forced by an idiotic policy: Cheat it not: Stay sensible. 100% line coverage is not any better than 97% line coverage.

Comment: The question is quite popular (although downvoted) showing an issue.
I'm not saying we should always aim towards 100% code coverage but that there is an issue that some parts of the code cannot be covered by tests at all...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `log.Print` instead of `log.Fatal` and return the error value that you declared in signature of function `checkIfReadable`. Or don't the error it and return it to some place that knows better how to handle it.

The function `log.Fatal` is strictly for reporting your program's *final breath*.

Calling `log.Fatal` is a bit worse than calling panic (there is also `log.panic`), because it does not execute deferred calls. Remember, that overusing `panic` in Go is considered a bad style.

Comment: So "program's" means "program's, test's and anything that might come with it".

Comment: Yes, it means the running process.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get 100% test coverage and not fail at the same time is to use `recover()` to catch the panic that is thrown by `log.Fatalf()`.

Here are the docs for [recover](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#recover). I think it fits your use case nicely.

Comment: `log.Fatalf` calls `os.Exit`, so `recover` will not help.

Comment: Indeed, I just double checked the docs.

The above does not help.